# Timeouts from logical replication with no obvious root cause

Tags: postgresql, replication

Logical replication from PG 15.3 to 15.3 has been running without problems until a few days ago.

Now the subscriber shows repeated messages like:

```
2023-07-29 08:25:04.523 UTC [26] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 8692 buffers (53.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 1 removed, 14 recycled; write=269.921 s, sync=0.485 s, total=270.438 s; sync files=37, longest=0.224 s, average=0.014 s; distance=230568 kB, estimate=436766 kB

2023-07-29 08:25:34.550 UTC [26] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time

2023-07-29 08:27:55.699 UTC [142] ERROR:  could not receive data from WAL stream: server closed the connection unexpectedly

        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.

2023-07-29 08:27:55.702 UTC [159] LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "<SUB_NAME>" has started

2023-07-29 08:27:55.706 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 142) exited with exit code 1
```

And the publisher shows repeated messages like:

```
2023-07-29 08:24:50.341 UTC [530982] STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "<SUB NAME>" LOGICAL 37D1/1E0DD9A0 (proto_version '3', publication_names '"<PUB NAME>"')
2023-07-29 08:27:36.956 UTC [530982] LOG:  terminating walsender process due to replication timeout
2023-07-29 08:27:36.956 UTC [530982] CONTEXT:  slot "<SUB NAME>", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN 37D0/F9E8C2E8
```

I can connect using `psql` from either node back to the other. As far as I have been able to determine no routing or firewall changes have been made.

Reading other similar reports suggests that deleting and recreating th sub will fix the problem, but I'd like to understand/avoid it.

Any suggestions on how to track this down would be appreciated.

Edit: Further investigation shows the "logical replication worker" 100% CPU bound but no current command in pg_stat_activity.

Comment: Is replication completely stalled due to this?  Perhaps it is proceeding and just spamming your logs occasionally.

Comment: The subscription is completely stalled. Only one subscription in total.

Comment: I don't know what is causing it (in my attempts to reproduce, I get the messages but the replication does advance between messages), but you can try increasing the wal_sender_timeout on the publisher side to see it it clears the problem.

Comment: To debug further, I would run `strace -y` or `gdb` on the logical replication worker to see if you can figure out what it is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was an application design issue combined with O(n^2) update performance due to an edge-case in postgres.

The app had triggers on the replicated tables which computed basic statistics on the updates. Among other things it maintained a count of certain types of changes.

In one pathological case, there were more than 150k updates to this row inside a single transaction. This is known to cause O(n^2) performance degradation as PG writes repeated copies of the rows then has to find those rows on the next update.

The timeout was simply caused by the extraordinarily slow update.

The solution was to avoid collecting these particular statistics. Another solution would be to write multiple rows but that comes with it's own issues, and the statistics were not absolutely necessary.